# AJAX Call is not working in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

My AJAX Call is working fine in all browsers including IE 8,9,10,11 in my Windows 8 machine

But the same code is not working in my friend's machine who has windows 7 and IE 11 installed. Though the same code is working on his other browsers i.e. Firfox, Chrome etc.

My AJAX call is as below

```
str = "type=checkloginstatus";
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "random.php?"+$.now(),
    cache : false,
    data: str
    }).done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How does it not work? What is the error returned by the call?

Comment: There is no response from call, and it also not sending my post data, I had checked in developer tools

Comment: And no error in the console prior to the call?

Comment: no, there are no errors in console ! though the call is working fine in my machine with same browser !

Comment: Your friend's browser might be running an add-on that tampers with the request. Try running IE with the `-extoff` command line option to see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: Ok, let me try it out

Comment: yes, there was google toolbar installed in IE and which was stopping AJAX call. Wow !! works like a charm ! You're great !! Thanks !

Comment: i have disabled extension but didn't work also.. @UditTrivedi

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem. Windows 7 and IE 11 is a bad combination. When I run my AJAX (called `ajaxB.asp` from the url line in IE11 it returns data. However if I run it from within my html page it returns NOTHING!
Code:

```
function winkeltonen(dm)
{ 
$.get(
    "ajax/ajaxB.asp",
        {stand: dm},
    function (data) {
        if (data == '...') // empty
            {
            $('#DYNdeel2').hide();
            }
            else
        {
            document.getElementById('DYNbal').innerHTML = data;
                $('#DYNdeel2').show();
        }
    });
}
```

It runs fine in  opera and Firefox and all IE's before 11

Comment: Please add answer not comment here!